# Difference between Native debugging and managed debugging?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im looking to try and set up remote debugging for a VB project in Visual Studio 2010. On the MSDN page it mentions both Native debugging and managed debugging (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t(v=vs.100).aspx), but I dont know what they mean. Can someone enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: Managed is .NET code, native is c/c++. (quick example) I'm not sure about unsafe code.

Answer (score 2):

**Managed** is for .NET languages like C# and VB.NET.

**Native** is for compiled-to-machine-code languages like C and C++.